# PHP: Issues with querying multiple tables

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My search function works well when it queries just a single table. But when I query more than one table in the same database (using 'UNION'), am faced with 2 issues:

**1**. `$query` (specifically the line: `if ( ! $query->num_rows )`) gives
    the error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in function.php line 18`.

I think this has to do with how the array is to be accessed now that
it holds rows from multiple tables?

**2.**  Once I do get these values, am unsure how to extract the field information from the different tables. As long as there was one table, this foreach loop was fine:

```
foreach($_SESSION['search_output']['results'] as $value){ 
echo $value->title; 
echo"<br>";
}
```

However how would one access the differently named fields when there are multiple tables. I was thinking of switch-case, but how to I get the table name using the procedural approach?

Would appreciate any help in understanding how to approach this.

Following are the files
**function.php**

```
<?php    
function search($conn, $search_term) {
    $sanitized =  $conn->real_escape_string($search_term);

    $query = $conn->query("(SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR body LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR sources LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' 
      OR date LIKE '%{$sanitized}%')
      UNION
      (SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventname LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR eventsumm LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR eventdate LIKE '%{$sanitized}%')
      UNION
      (SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE rectitle LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR recsummary LIKE '%{$sanitized}%')
      UNION
      (SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE bookname LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR revbody LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR revsource LIKE '%{$sanitized}%')
      UNION
      (SELECT * FROM foodiq WHERE iqitem LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR iqbody LIKE '%{$sanitized}%')");


    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
      return false;
    }

 $rows = array(); // ADD THIS
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows
    );

    return $search_results;
  }
  ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once  ('setup.php');
require_once  ('function.php');
    if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
  $search_results='';
  $search_term = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_results = search($conn, $search_term);  
  }
?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
                <label>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="searchitem" name="s">
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">              
</form>

  <?php if (isset($search_results)) : 
  print_r($search_results); exit;
        $_SESSION['search_output'] = $search_results; 
        header("Location: final.php");
        exit;
   endif; ?>

<body>
</html>
```

**final.php**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 



<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['search_output']) && is_array($_SESSION['search_output'])) 
{ 
echo $_SESSION['search_output']['count']. " result(s) found <br>";
foreach($_SESSION['search_output']['results'] as $value){ 
echo $value->title; 
echo"<br>";
}

} 
else
echo "Sorry, no results found"; 


?> 

<body> 
</html>
```

**setup.php**

```
    <?php
    $hn = 'localhost';
    $db = 'kkh';
    $un = 'water';
    $pw = 'water'; 



    #DB Connection:
     $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
     if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **YOU SHOULD** check if there any connection errors like right after `->query`:

   ```
   /* check error */
   if ($conn->error) {
       printf("Query failed: %s\n", $conn->error);
       exit();
   }
   ```

   Please not it's not the same as `$conn->connect_error`.
2. You may access your fields using field names of your 1st table in union statement.

   Let's assume the table `news` has these fields: `id`, `title`, `author`, `date_created`. Then simply use `$row->id`, `$row->title`, etc.

   To know which table is related with a relevant row you may want to use something like:

   ```
   SELECT *, 'news' AS source FROM news .... 
       UNION 
   SELECT *, 'events' AS source FROM events ...
   ```

   and then `$row->source` will contain your table.
3. Please note that when you use `UNION` statement all fields in every `SELECT` **must** have the same number of columns! [Read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Comment: there are no connection errors.  I ran
`if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
?>`                                            2. yes, this is how to access the fields, but I wish to know how to identify which table a row belongs to in $value, so I can access its field. ie. how do i find what the table is from $value?

Comment: `object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(1222) ["error"]=> string(61) "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" ["error_list"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["errno"]=> int(1222) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "21000" ["error"]=> string(61) ...

Comment: Also there is no connection error with just a single table - so I don't think it is a connection error.

Comment: yes, it has to do with #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns